# Iniciar Laravel junto com WebServer

Tags: php

Tenho o Laravel instalado em um WebServer, mas toda vez que preciso testar uma página tenho que digitar no terminal:  php artisan serve --host=IP_DO_SERVIDOR.

Como faço para que o Laravel inicie junto com o WebServer
?

Comment: Esse servidor é Linux? Qual distro?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, Laravel  5.4.15, PHP 7.0.15,  MysSQL 5.7.17.

Comment: Instale um bom servidor web, criei um vhost e seja feliz!

Answer (score -1):

Para executar um script ao iniciar o Ubuntu, você pode usar um cronjob (tem outras maneiras, essa eu acho mais fácil).

Para isso, crie um arquivo com o comando que você deseja, e coloque a extensão `.sh`. No caso, você pode criar na sua home (`/home/[usuario]`) um arquivo chamado `laravel_start.sh` e incluir nele o `php artisan serve --host=IP_DO_SERVIDOR`. Após salvar, execute o seguinte comando:

```
chmod +x /home/[usuario]/laravel_start.sh
```

Isso dá permissão para executar o arquivo.

Depois, execute:

`crontab -e`

Isso vai abrir o arquivo de tarefas do `cron`, provavelmente no `nano`. Vá até o fim do arquivo e coloque a seguinte linha:

```
@reboot /home/[usuario]/laravel_start.sh
```

Salve o arquivo e saia apertando `ctrl+x` e confirmando a alteração.

Dá um boot e vê se ele inicia direitinho.

Comment: Agradeço demais o seu detalhamento, mas ao digitar crontab -e, então é apresentado esses arquivos

Comment: Agradeço demais o seu detalhamento, mas ao inserir @reboot /home/[usuario]/laravel_start.sh no crontab, não foi pedido confirmação de alteração.